# Recursion calculation for how many level and numbers of children it has

Tags: java, database, algorithm, recursion

The source is:

```
id, pid,name
1,  0,  a
2,  1,  b
3,  1,  c
```

The result we expected is:

```
id,pid,name,upnum,uplevel,downum,downlevel
1,  0,  a,  0,    0,      2,     1  
2,  1,  b,  1,    1,      0,     0
3,  1,  c,  1,    1,      0,     0
```

Here,name is the name of person,id identify each person,pid means parent id,for example,the person a is the superior of the person b.
upnum means how many superiors he has totally,uplevel means how many level of superiors he has,downnum and downlevel is almost like this

For get this result,I think I have two way

1.Use database,like oralce,I use `connect by` and `nocycle`,everything is ok.But for each person,I must run the "connect by" sql again,it seems slow.
And we must install a oracle on the client side,some client do not like it.
If we use h2 or some embed database,can we use the feature of `nocycle` in oracle?but I guess it is slow too.Or we should make of index of id?

2.Use java hashMap to store the relationships of id and pid,but when the data become large,there may be a out of memory exception.How to write the code?

What is the best way?
Or is there a better way?like some graph algorithm,or graph-db(database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real need for a database. A simple iteration and a recursive function can do the analysis needed :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Graph {

    private final List<Node> nodes;
    private final Node root;

    //Graph assumes unique id > 0, and only root with pid = 0
    Graph(Node root){
        this.root = root;
        nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        nodes.add(root);
    };

    void add(Node node){
        nodes.add(node);
    }

    void analyze(){
        //sort by pid so iteration goes from top level down
        nodes.sort( (n1,n2) -> Integer.compare(n1.getPid(), n2.getPid()) );
        for(Node node : nodes){
            Node parent = getNode(node.getPid());
            if (parent == null ) {
                continue;  //skip root
            }
            node.setUpLevel(parent.getUpLevel()+1);  //add 1 to parent value
            node.setUpNum(node.getUpNum() +1);       //increment by 1
            parent.setDowNum(parent.getDowNum() +1); //increment by 1
            updateHigherLevels(node);
        }
    }

    //recursively update higher levels
    private void updateHigherLevels(Node node) {
        Node parent = getNode(node.getPid());
        if(parent == null) return;
        parent.setDownLevel(node.getDownLevel() + 1);
        updateHigherLevels(parent);
    }

    void print(){
        //sort by id for nice printing
        nodes.sort( (n1,n2) -> Integer.compare(n1.getId(), n2.getId()) );
        String format = "\n%2s %3s %4s %5s %7s %7s  %8s";
        System.out.printf(format,"id","pid","name","upnum","uplevel", "downnum" , "downlevel");
        for(Node node : nodes){
            System.out.printf(format, node.getId(), node.getPid(), node.getName(), node.getUpNum(), node.getUpLevel()
                    , node.getDowNum(), node.getDownLevel());
        }
    }

    Node getNode(int id){

        for(Node node : nodes){
            if(node.getId() == id) return node;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //make graph
        Graph graph = new Graph(new Node(1, 0, "a"));
        graph.add(new Node(2, 1, "b"));
        graph.add(new Node(3, 1, "c"));
        graph.add(new Node(4, 2, "d"));
        graph.add(new Node(5, 2, "e"));

        graph.analyze();
        graph.print();
    }
}

class Node {

    private final int id,pid;
    private int upnum = 0, uplevel = 0, downum = 0,  downlevel = 0;
    private final String name;

    Node(int id, int pid, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    int getId() { return id; }

    int getPid() { return pid;  }

    String getName() { return name; }

    int getUpNum() { return upnum;  }

    void setUpNum(int upnum) { this.upnum = upnum; }

    int getUpLevel() { return uplevel; }

    void setUpLevel(int uplevel) { this.uplevel = uplevel; }

    int getDowNum() { return downum; }

    void setDowNum(int downum) { this.downum = downum; }

    int getDownLevel() { return downlevel; }

    void setDownLevel(int downlevel) { this.downlevel = downlevel; }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What about a infinite loop,like,A is B's parent,and B is A's parent? Or B- A -C- B?

Comment: You mean a graph with cycles. Did you test it ? Anyway I do not see this in the original question. I would appreciate feedback on the answer to the original question before diverting to new questions.

Comment: I have tested it,it is correct base on original question.If A is B's parent,and B is A's parent,no infinite loop but 2 node called A appears.Anyway,I will try myself first.My question is not like a separate question,but I have mentioned a little about oracle `nocycle` and `out of memory`.